# Scrollspy Highlighting Two Targets

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, razor, scrollspy

Scrollspy is highlighting two targets at the same time which is not what I want. I want it to only highlight one. It does highlight one, but when scrolling between the two elements it highlights both.

[image: Nav bar highlighting]

CSHTML

```
var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
<script>
    $(function() {
        setupJumpNav("#@guid");
    });
</script>
<div>
    <div class="jump-container">
        <nav class="jump hide-on-small-only" style="top: 50px;" id="@guid">
            <ul class="section @(tabs.Count > 3 ? "center" : "")">
                @foreach (var tab in tabs)
                {
                    <li>
                        <a href="#@tab.Title.Replace(" ", "_").ToLower()">@tab.Title</a>
                    </li>
                }
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="socialMediaButtons socialMediaCentered"></div>
    <div class="container">
        @foreach (var tab in tabs)
        {
            <article class="col s12 section scrollspy" id="@tab.Title.Replace(" ", "_").ToLower()">
                @foreach (var contentItem in tab.RealContentItems)
                {
                    @Display(Model.ContentItem.ContentManager.BuildDisplay(contentItem))
                }
            </article>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
(function() {
    setupJumpNav = function(guid) {
        var updatePushpin = function() {
            $(guid).pushpin("remove");
            var jumpTop = $(guid).parent().offset().top;
            $(guid).pushpin({
                top: $(".hide-on-med-and-down").css("display") !== "none" ? jumpTop - 25 : jumpTop,
                offset: $(".hide-on-med-and-down").css("display") !== "none" ? 75 : 50
            });
        };
        updatePushpin();
        $(window).bind("orientationchange resize", updatePushpin);
        $(guid).parent().parent().find(".scrollspy").each(function() {
            $(this).scrollSpy();
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scrollspy was being called more than once.

```
   $(guid).parent().parent().find(".scrollspy").each(function() {
        $(this).scrollSpy();
    });
```

Should be

```
    $(guid).parent().parent().find(".scrollspy").scrollSpy();
```